# Getting firebase error when trying to authenticate with google with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting this error in the console

```
Cannot read property 'ac' of undefined
```

when I try to run this code in react:

[Home.js](https://gist.github.com/mastari/21aa8b25bb784b96decd030aa22ef334)

[Firebase.js](https://gist.github.com/mastari/8aac0b7f8b8c9c502eececcf4f1eee15)

I am using webpack dev server, but I dont get any errors in the dev server console. And yes, I do have the firebase node module installed.

Comment: can you provide the code, so that it will be helpful

Comment: Click on the links for the code

Comment: Provide details how this error is thrown. It's not obvious where to look in your code. Which line is throwing this error.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. My minified js was missing certain things making it unreadable. I reinstalled Firebase v4 and it is working fine.